# If a function restricted to every set of an open cover is $C^k$, then is the function $C^k$

Tags: analysis

I know that a function $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is continuous if $f|_{U_{\alpha}}:U_\alpha\longrightarrow Y$ is continuous for every $U_\alpha$, where the collection $\{U_\alpha\}$ is an open cover for $X$.

Now can a similar statement be made about differentiable functions? My guess is that, yes, it can be made, because differentiability is defined pointwise. Is that right? What about $C^k$ functions?

I have this doubt because I have a function say $\phi$ which when restricted to each subset of an open cover of $X$ is $C^k$. But I want to conclude that $f:X\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $C^k$. Is that possible?

Comment: differentiability is a local property, so the answer is yeah then say are $C^k$

Answer (score 0):

Differentiability is a local property, you define a function is continuous in $x_0$ when 
$$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+ A \cdot h + r(h)$$
with $$\lim_{\|h\| \to 0} \frac{r(h)}{\|h\|} = 0$$

A function is called differentiable if it is differentiable in each point. So when you have a normed space (which is requiered for my definition of differentiability) than the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: According to the book I am reading, if U ⊂ Rd, then f:U⟶R is $C^k$ on $U$ if the first partials exist and are $C^{k−1}$ on $U$. So here being $C^k$ is not directly defined pointwise. So how do I prove that f is $C^k$ if the restriction of f to each set in the open cover is $C^k$. Can you give me some hint?